# Hide a Label in CSS

Tags: css, label

I need to hide a label with CSS

```
<p class="half_form ">
<label for="property_bathrooms">Bathrooms (*only numbers)</label>
<input type="text" id="property_bathrooms" size="40" class="form-control" name="property_bathrooms" value="0"></p>
```

I am trying to use:

```
label [for="property_bathrooms"]
{
    display:none;
}
```

As seen in other question but is not working for me.
Any help is very appeciated.

Comment: did you tried removing the space between label[for=

Comment: Yes, thanks! This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space after label

```
label[for="property_bathrooms"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem